# Cannot display data from MySQL in Jtable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I am new to java and I try to learn by reading the examples I find in stackoverflow and on github.
What I would create: a combox with months and years which will point to a DB, collect the data and display them
Since its too difficult for my knowledge I tried hard coding the year and inputting the month, but nothing is shown.

Some little notes: I found some code to display the database but I am not able to insert a button and pass the input to the DB then I found another piece of code which uses the button and allows me to read the db.

I put them together but after pressing the button nothing happens.

Tried to debug it with netbeans and all data from db are correctly load and stored but don't show.

This is my mess. Please be patient.

```
      class CapiAbbigliamento extends JFrame { //implements ActionListener {
     
      // GUI Swing
      JTable taglie;
      JList capi;
      DefaultListModel listModel;
      //MyTableModel mtb;
      JButton cerca;
      JTextField capo_text,input_mese;
      
      
      private JLabel nome_label;
      private CapoDiAbbigliamento cda; //This is the part commented out of the code
      private CapiAbbigliamento ca;
      private Connection con;
      private Statement stm;
      private ResultSet rs;
      private ResultSet count;
      
      
      CapiAbbigliamento() {
        super("My Job");
         
        try {
          
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
              con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"xxxx","yyy");
              stm = con.createStatement();
        
            } catch(Exception sqlex) {
              String error = sqlex.getMessage();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,error,"Errore!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
              System.exit(1);
            }
        
        
        // Left panel
        /
            JPanel left_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            left_panel.setOpaque(true);
            left_panel.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,255));
        
            listModel = new DefaultListModel();
            capi = new JList(listModel);
            capi.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
            capi.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
            capi.setSelectionForeground(new Color(153,50,204));
        
            JScrollPane scrollList = new JScrollPane(capi);
            left_panel.add(scrollList);
        
            // Pannello contenente tutti gli elementi di destra
            JPanel right_panel = new JPanel(null);
            right_panel.setOpaque(true);
            right_panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        
        
    
        // Ricerca
        JPanel ricerca = new JPanel(null);
        ricerca.setBackground(new Color(00,255,00));
        
        cerca = new JButton("GO");
        cerca.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 9));
        nome_label = new JLabel("Mese");
        input_mese = new JTextField(10);
        
        nome_label.setBounds(5,5,50,20);
        input_mese.setBounds(50,5,40,20);
        cerca.setBounds(100,5,50,20);
        
        
        // Aggiungo gli elementi
        ricerca.add(nome_label);
        ricerca.add(input_mese);
        ricerca.add(cerca);
        
        
        // Posiziono i pannelli
        ricerca.setBounds(400,10,160,30);
        right_panel.add(ricerca);
        
        
        // inserisco il pannello di destra nello split, così come il pannello di sinistra
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,left_panel, right_panel);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(500);
        
        // Aggiungo gli elementi al pannello di contenuto
        getContentPane().add(splitPane);
        
        // Riferito al campo di ricerca
            cerca.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {
            String mese = input_mese.getText();
                
            if(mese.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please, SELECT A MONTH");
            return;}
                
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            int anno = now.getYear();
            //int month; // = now.getMonthValue();
            //int daysinmonth = now.lengthOfMonth();
                
            caricaDati(anno, mese);
        });
    } // Fine costruttore
      
      // Legge i dati nel db e crea gli opportuni oggetti
        public void caricaDati(int anno, String mese) {
        
            listModel.clear();
            ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
            
            LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
            int daysinmonth = now.lengthOfMonth();
            try {
          
                String sql_nbr = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM alldata WHERE anno =  '"+anno+"' AND mese = '"+mese+"' GROUP BY anno, mese";
                count = stm.executeQuery(sql_nbr);
                if (!count.next()) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Combinazione ANNO-MESE non esistente");}
              
                String query = "SELECT * FROM alldata WHERE anno =  '"+anno+"' AND mese = '"+mese+"' ";
                rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
          
          /*****int i;
              String day;
               while(rs.next()) {
               for (i = 1; i <= daysinmonth; i++)
                    { 
                      
                    day = "d" + i;  
                    String what;
                    what = rs.getString(day);
                    String nome = rs.getString("nome");
                    cda = new CapoDiAbbigliamento(nome,i);        
                    //cda = new CapoDiAbbigliamento(what,i);
                    cda.addTaglia(new Taglia(nome,i));
                    }   
            listModel.addElement(cda);
            
            } ****/
        
              ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                int columns = md.getColumnCount() - 1;
    
                //  Get column names
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                { columnNames.add( md.getColumnName(i) ); }
    
                //  Get row data
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    ArrayList row = new ArrayList(columns);
    
                    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                    {  
                        String pippo = rs.getString(i);
                        String dummy;
                        switch (pippo)
                        {
                            
                            case "V" : dummy = String.valueOf('V');
                                       if (dummy.equals(pippo))
                                       { pippo = "--"; row.add(pippo); }    
                                       else {row.add( rs.getObject(i) ); }
                                       break;
                            /// many other cases
                            default  :  row.add( rs.getObject(i) ); break;          
                        }    
                    }
                    data.add( row );
                }
                rs.close();
                } catch(SQLException sqlex) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sqlex.getMessage().toString()); sqlex.printStackTrace();}
      
      
        // Create Vectors and copy over elements from ArrayLists to them
        // Vector is deprecated but I am using them in this example to keep 
        // things simple - the best practice would be to create a custom defined
        // class which inherits from the AbstractTableModel class
            Vector columnNamesVector = new Vector();
            Vector dataVector = new Vector();
    
            for ( int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            {
                ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
                Vector subVector = new Vector();
                for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++)
                { ubVector.add(subArray.get(j)); }
                dataVector.add(subVector);
            }
    
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ )
                columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));
                JTable table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector);
                table.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11));
                table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
    
                {
                    TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
                    int preferredWidth = tableColumn.getMinWidth();
                    int maxWidth = tableColumn.getMaxWidth();
                    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
                    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
                    {
                        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                        Component c = table.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
            
                        int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + table.getIntercellSpacing().width;
                        preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, width);
    
                        if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
                        {
                            preferredWidth = maxWidth;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( preferredWidth );
        
                    for (int row = 0; row < table.getColumnCount(); row++)
                    {
                        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(row).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
                    }
                }
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table);
                //JScrollPane sscrollPane = 
                new JScrollPane(scrollPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                    Component add = getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
        }
      
          
          
          
          public static void main(String[] args) {
      
            CapiAbbigliamento frame = new CapiAbbigliamento();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame.setSize(960,600);
            frame.setLocation(200,100);
            frame.setVisible(true);    
        
      }

}
```

This is the class MyCellRenderer

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
  private DefaultListCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
  
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    JLabel label = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list,value,index,isSelected,cellHasFocus);
    CapoDiAbbigliamento cda = (CapoDiAbbigliamento) value;
    for(Taglia t:cda.getTaglie()) {
      if(t.getQuantita() <= 10) {
        label.setForeground(Color.RED);
        break;
      } else if((t.getQuantita() <= 15) && (t.getQuantita() > 10)) {
        label.setForeground(new Color(255,140,0));
      }
      else {
        label.setForeground(new Color(0,100,0));
      }
    }
    return label;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. Where is class `MyTableModel`? Where is class `CapoDiAbbigliamento`? Where is class `MyCellRenderer`? Where is the declaration of variable `ubVector`? These are not all the compilation problems, but please [edit] your question and add the missing details.

Comment: The code compile without errors. Your first two notes are not used. They are part of a program I dont use, MyCellRenderer is part of the project and ubVector is crearly a typo

Comment: The code of class `MyCellRenderer` that you posted, references class `CapoDiAbbigliamento`. Excuse me, but I can't find the code for class `CapoDiAbbigliamento`. `MyCellRenderer` also references class `Taglia`. I can't find the code for that class either. What am I missing?

Comment: `CapoDiAbbigliamento` is part of the project but I dont use. About `Taglia`... didnt notice it. I beg your pardon but the original writer of the project used to call everything in in the worst way in the world (CapoAbbigliamento and CapoDiAbbigliamento) so I missed `Taglia`. Will check everything a let you know